# Jquery :How to Get Selected Option Full Text (with Spaces)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I m using jQuery to get selected option text value.
    problem is that it retruns only initial text till space come.

```
My requirment as follow.

    <select id='list'>
    <option value='1'>This Is Option A</option>
    <option value='2'>This Is Option B</option>
    <option value='3'>This Is Option c</option>
</select>

<script>
alert($('#list').find('option:selected').text());
</script>

*IT Returns only 'This' instead of 'This Is Option A'*

Please Help
```

Comment: Try `.html()` instead.

Comment: why don't you http://jsfiddle.net/ your code? and also put appropriate JQuery library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Its working as expected, check this demo,
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/02e11v2p/

Answer (score 0):

As swetha chinchore said, it is working fine, try to use the latest jquery library..

**Script**

```
$("#list").change(function(){
    alert($(this).find("option:selected").text());
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/du0kfw3k/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alert(document.getElementById('list').options[document.getElementById('list').selectedIndex].outerHTML);
```